# Airflow EventTriggersFunctionOperator (Kafka) not working in deferred state

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow

I'm trying to implement the example in https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/main/example_dags/listener_dag_function.py , just updating a bit the code to work in Airflow 2.2

However, the dag `fizz buzz` just finish successfully instantly, and the dag `listener_dag function` is not showing up, so the `await_function` is not entering the deferred state as it should, and thus, it isn't able to listen messages from topic. Also, when running `airflow dags list` it only shows the `fizz buzz` dag, but not the `listener_dag_function` dag

Here's my code

```
# listener_dag_function.py
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import functools
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow_provider_kafka.operators.event_triggers_function import (
    EventTriggersFunctionOperator,
)
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

import random
import string


def generate_uuid():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return "".join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(6))


kf_config = {
    "bootstrap.servers": Variable.get("kf_bootstrap_servers"),
    "group.id": "campanas",
    "enable.auto.commit": True,
    "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "security.protocol": "sasl_ssl",
    "sasl.mechanisms": 'PLAIN',
    "sasl.username": Variable.get("kf_username"),
    "sasl.password": Variable.get("kf_password"),
}

with DAG("listener_dag_function",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    def await_function(message):
        val = message.value()
        val = val.decode('utf-8')
        print(f"Value in message is {val}")
        if val % 3 == 0:
            return val
        if val % 5 == 0:
            return val

    def pick_downstream_dag(message, **context):
        if message % 15 == 0:
            TriggerDagRunOperator(
                trigger_dag_id="fizz_buzz", task_id=f"{message}{generate_uuid()}"
            ).execute(context)
        else:
            if message % 3 == 0:
                print("FIZZ !")
            if message & 5 == 0:
                print("BUZZ !")

    listen_for_message = EventTriggersFunctionOperator(
        task_id="listen_for_message_fizz_buzz",
        topics=[Variable.get("kf_inbound_topic")],
        apply_function='listener_dag_function.await_function',  # this needs to be passed in as a module, function direct does not work!!!!
        kafka_config=kf_config,
        event_triggered_function=pick_downstream_dag,
    )

with DAG("fizz_buzz",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    def hello_4():
        print("FIZZ BUZZ")

    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id="hello_kafka_mongo", python_callable=hello_4)
```

The logs shows the following:

```
*** Reading local file: /Users/imagemaker/airflow/logs/fizz_buzz/hello_kafka_mongo/2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00/1.log
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: fizz_buzz.hello_kafka_mongo scheduled__2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: fizz_buzz.hello_kafka_mongo scheduled__2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): hello_kafka_mongo> on 2023-02-22 00:41:00+00:00
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 11256 to run task
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fizz_buzz', 'hello_kafka_mongo', 'scheduled__2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00', '--job-id', '27', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/campaigns_to_touch-policy.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/jv/3_2b3pp556qcwq6f0pq5vp880000gn/T/tmp205xg8cs', '--error-file', '/var/folders/jv/3_2b3pp556qcwq6f0pq5vp880000gn/T/tmpd6y1gc5w']
[2023-02-21, 18:42:16 -03] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 27: Subtask hello_kafka_mongo
[2023-02-21, 18:42:21 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: fizz_buzz.hello_kafka_mongo scheduled__2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00 [running]> on host MacBook-Pro-de-Imagemaker.local
[2023-02-21, 18:42:26 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py:323 SAWarning: TypeDecorator UtcDateTime(timezone=True) will not produce a cache key because the ``cache_ok`` attribute is not set to True.  This can have significant performance implications including some performance degradations in comparison to prior SQLAlchemy versions.  Set this attribute to True if this type object's state is safe to use in a cache key, or False to disable this warning. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/cprf)
[2023-02-21, 18:42:26 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/renderedtifields.py:126 SAWarning: TypeDecorator UtcDateTime(timezone=True) will not produce a cache key because the ``cache_ok`` attribute is not set to True.  This can have significant performance implications including some performance degradations in comparison to prior SQLAlchemy versions.  Set this attribute to True if this type object's state is safe to use in a cache key, or False to disable this warning. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/cprf)
[2023-02-21, 18:42:26 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/renderedtifields.py:162 SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/renderedtifields.py:159 SAWarning: TypeDecorator UtcDateTime(timezone=True) will not produce a cache key because the ``cache_ok`` attribute is not set to True.  This can have significant performance implications including some performance degradations in comparison to prior SQLAlchemy versions.  Set this attribute to True if this type object's state is safe to use in a cache key, or False to disable this warning. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/cprf)
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {taskinstance.py:1427} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=fizz_buzz
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=hello_kafka_mongo
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-02-22T00:41:00+00:00
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - FIZZ BUZZ
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {python.py:152} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {taskinstance.py:1270} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=fizz_buzz, task_id=hello_kafka_mongo, execution_date=20230222T004100, start_date=20230222T004216, end_date=20230222T004227
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1076 SADeprecationWarning: Query.value() is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please use Query.with_entities() in combination with Query.scalar() (deprecated since: 1.4)
[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /Users/imagemaker/airflow/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1076 SADeprecationWarning: Query.values() is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please use Query.with_entities() (deprecated since: 1.4)
```

Comment: `start_date` should be in year 2022?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it does not matter, as long it is before the current date

Comment: Can you post your triggerer and scheduler logs please ? Also - this will not run in Airflow 2.0, you'll need at least 2.2 for deferrable operators

Comment: @dstorey I've updated the question, since I'm using Airflow 2.2 . As I mentioned, can see the "fizz_buzz" dag when running the code. I've included the logs

Comment: The downstream dag `fizz_buzz` is triggering  here
`[2023-02-21, 18:42:27 -03] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - FIZZ BUZZ` 

Are you expecting a different behavior ?

Comment: @dstorey thats not he problem. I already explained that the fizz_buzz runs successfully and then ends, instead of wait for a kafka message, and only then run. I also explained that the listener_dag_function dag is not showing up, so the await function does not enter in the deferred state as it should

Comment: Scheduler logs ?